# Using qDebug causes google test to not run

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, googletest

I'm trying to use google test for QT Creator. Whenever I try to run a test that calls a function that uses qDebug some of the tests will not run (0 pass, 0 failed, no errors). The test will run fine if I remove the qDebug and use something like cout instead. Running all the tests or running them individually has the same issue. If I debug the test, it runs to completion, it doesn't seem to get hung up on anything.

I have a class that is being built as a shared library that is a simple main window with a button. Clicking on the button just increments a counter. I added this library to my google test project.

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOWLIB_H
#define MAINWINDOWLIB_H

#include "MainWindowLib_global.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MAINWINDOWLIB_EXPORT MainWindowLib : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindowLib(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindowLib();
    int getCounter();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int counter = 0;

public slots:
    void button1Pressed();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOWLIB_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindowlib.h"
#include "ui_mainwindowLib.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <QDebug>

MainWindowLib::MainWindowLib(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindowLib::button1Pressed);
}

MainWindowLib::~MainWindowLib()
{
    delete(ui);
}

int MainWindowLib::getCounter()
{
//    qDebug() << "Counter is: " << this->counter;
    return this->counter;
}

void MainWindowLib::button1Pressed()
{
    this->counter++;
//    qDebug() << "Counter is: " << this->counter;
    std::cout << "Counter is: " << this->counter << std::endl;
}
```

The Tests:

```
TEST_F(TestClass1, dummyTest1)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(1, 1);
}

TEST_F(TestClass1, testGetCount)
{
    int argc = 0;
    char *argv[1] = {NULL};

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindowLib myWindow;

    int count = myWindow.getCounter();
    ASSERT_EQ(count, 0);
}

TEST_F(TestClass1, testButtonPressed)
{
    int argc = 0;
    char *argv[1] = {NULL};

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindowLib myWindow;

    emit myWindow.button1Pressed();
    int count = myWindow.getCounter();

    ASSERT_EQ(count, 1);
}

TEST_F(TestClass1, dummyTest2)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(4, 4);
}
```

Tests all pass when not using qDebug:

[image: No qDebug]

Only two tests get ran when putting back in qDebug for both functions:

[image: with qDebug]

When I try to run the tests individually the buttonPressed and GetCount test won't run. If I debug them they run and pass.

Am I setting up my tests incorrectly for qt applications?